# Right Click menu on a LocatorPane graphic in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, contextmenu, graphic

When graphics are right-clicked in Mathematica you get a context menu (cut graphics, copy graphics, save graphics as,...), but for a LocatorPane Graphic this right click menu is disable.
How can I call a context menu for a LocatorPane graphics with an EventHandler or a MouseAction command in Mathematica? What command creates this menu?

```
LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]]
```

I find this code to open "Save as" Window in mathematica.

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["SelectionSaveSpecial"]]
```

I want  when i right click a LocatorPane graphic the "Save As" window open.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Jalil! Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) below that you like and if one of them answers your question to your satisfaction, please accept it by using the check-mark next to the answer. You can change your choice whenever you like.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  That is much more clear.

Comment: Is your purpose to save an image of the LocatorPane, or something else?

Comment: I want to call "save graphic as" by right click on LocatorPane graphics.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I edited the question. Please see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> I want to call "save graphic as" by right click on LocatorPane graphics.

I have not yet found a way to do that, but you may not know that you can:

1. select the `LocatorPane` object by clicking in the white-space to the right of it and dragging left.
2. use menu `File > Save Selection As...` to save a graphic in your desired format.

---

What I believe is the correct option does not appear to work:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  ComponentwiseContextMenu -> {"GraphicsBox" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "GraphicsBox"], 
    "Graphics3DBox" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "Graphics3DBox"], 
    "LocatorPaneBox" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "GraphicsBox"], 
    "CellGroup" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "CellGroup"], 
    "CellBracket" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "CellBracket"], 
    "CellRange" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "CellRange"], 
    "CellInsertionPoint" -> 
     FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "CellInsertionPoint"]}
  ];
```

Specifically, the value for `"LocatorPaneBox" ->` was changed to `"GraphicsBox"` but it has no apparent effect.

On the other hand, changing the value for `"GraphicsBox" ->` *does* have an effect.

I suspect that because `LocatorPane` uses the mouse input, it captures the right-click attempt, and never passes it to the context menu mechanism.  Perhaps disabling the mouse as an input device for `LocatorPane` would correct this, but that does not seem practical.

---

Here is one way to implement your suggestion of using `"SelectionSaveSpecial"`:

```
Dynamic[EventHandler[
  LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]],
  {"MouseClicked", 2} :> 
   FrontEndExecute[
     SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
     SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, CellContents]; 
     FrontEndToken["SelectionSaveSpecial"]
   ]
]]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard On my machine the "Save As..." dialog appears but it saves nothing. No file is created in the target directory.

Comment: @Alexey yes, i tested it now, no file was created by save as menu.

Comment: @Alexey @Jalil what version are you using?  It works in Mathematica 7.0.1 on Windows XP.  Please also try it after removing the line `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];` , but I must first click inside the pane (move the selector) before right-click for this to work.  Also, what format are you trying to save to?  I used .GIF, perhaps not all of them work.  I'll explore that.

Comment: It appears that I can save to .gif, .jpg, and .png, but not .bmp, .pdf, or .emf.  Please try the first three and tell me if any of them work.  At least that would be a place to start.

Comment: @Jalil @Alexey I think I found the problem and a solution that allows saving to other formats.  I will edit my answer with it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i have _Mathematica 8.0.1_ and your code worked fine. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4):

Not the complete answer but the context menus of `Cell`s are controlled by the `ContextMenu` option of `Cell`. You can set the default context menu of `Cell`s with style `"Graphics"` for any cell you wish:

```
CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData[SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]], "Output", 
  ContextMenu -> 
   FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["ContextMenus", "Graphics"]]]
```

Comment: @Alexey: when i used this code:                        LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]]   , right click menu is disable and only left click is active. i want to have right click menu for a graphic on this example.

Comment: @Jalil I do not know how to enable right-click context menu on `LocatorPane` but for which purposes do you need it? You can select and then copy/paste `LocatorPane` by selecting it with mouse like ordinary text.

Comment: @Alexey by run `LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]]` a graphic is created. I can not copy this graphic by selecting it like a text. I want to have a right click menu same as other graphics.

Comment: @Jalil In really you can do it! Try `{LocatorPane[{1, 1}/2, Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]]}`. You just have to use keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V for copy-pasting it!

Comment: @Jalil For selecting the entire `Cell` content you could also double-click inside free area of the cell.